# SQL - Найти братьев и сестёр в БД по фамилии и отчеству

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, ms-access

В БД есть таблица "студенты", в которой есть следующие колонки "дата рождения", "фамилия" и "отчество" студентов.

Необходимо написать SQL-запрос, который будет находить братьев и сестер, основываясь на колонках "фамилия" и "отчество", а так же определять их разницу в возрасте, основываясь на разнице между датами их рождений.

Все бы ничего, если бы фамилии и отчества не склонялись в зависимости от пола. Т.е как определить отдельно братьев и отдельно сестер я еще вроде понимаю, но мне не понятно, как быть в ситуации, когда родственники брат и сестра.

Это вообще возможно? Может есть какой-нибудь способ не учитывать последние два символа в фамилии и отчестве?

Comment: "Гадя, а как твое отчество? Мне для себя - чисто поржать."

Comment: Создай таблицу соответствия (мужское отчество - женское отчество) и не парься. А ещё правильнее - таблицу (отчество - ИД), где все (и мужские. и женские) отчества от одного имени имеют одинаковый ИД, а от разных соответственно разные ИД. От некоторых имён возможно образование двух (и, может быть, даже более) разных отчеств.

Comment: Почему нет колонок "Имя", "Пол"? Я бы попробовал регулярками сравнивать взависимисти от пола. А правильно, если такая задача стоит, создать таблицу связи между родственниками. Лучшая половина часто фамилию меняет, иногда очень часто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Может есть какой-нибудь способ не учитывать последние два символа в фамилии и отчестве?

Такой способ есть и называется `substr`. Вообще, решать такую задачу на чистом SQL и для общего случая - знатное извращение (намекните преподавателю, что пытки запрещены международным законодательством; если это рабочая задача - выберите другой способ). Но для наиболее частых случаев я бы предложил следующее:

`substr(patronymic, 1, length(patronymic) - 2)` - отрезает последние 2 символа от отчества, дальше можно сравнивать. Если у вас есть казахи в списке - у них показателями отчества являются отдельные слова `ОГЛЫ` (мужской род) или `КЫЗЫ` (женский). Способ не сработает с парой `Ильич`/`Ильинична`, ее проще отдельно захардкодить.

С фамилиями сложнее, придется городить длинный список (по тому же принципу): `-ов/-ова`, `-ев/-ева`, `-ёв/-ёва`, `-ин/-ина`, `-ий, -ый/-ая, -яя`, остальные, емнип, не изменяются. То есть что-то вроде:

```
case when substr(family_name, -2) in ('ов', 'ев', 'ёв', 'ин') 
     then family_name
     when substr(family_name, -3) in ('ова', 'ева', 'ёва', 'ина') 
     then substr(family_name, 1, length(family_name) - 1)
     when substr(family_name, -2) in ('ий', 'ый', 'ая', 'яя') 
     then substr(family_name, 1, length(family_name) - 2)
     else family_name end
```

Это выражение вернет вам неизменяемую часть фамилии, далее ее надо сравнить с другой фамилией (обработанной так же). Процентов 90 - 95 (а может и больше) вы этим запросом покроете, я думаю.